# Combinatorics issue

Tags: combinatorics

I'm not figuring out how to solve a problem:

- There are N people;
- There are G groups of P people (such that G*P = N, all groups same size)

How many ways can I do this division of the N people?

Example 1:

```
N = 1
{a}                 1 group of 1
answer = 1
```

Example 2:

```
N = 3
{a, b, c},          3 groups of 1
{abc}               1 group  of 3
answer = 2
```

Example 3:

```
N = 10
{a,b,c,...,j},                               10 groups of 1
{ab,cd,..,ij}, {ab,ce,df,...,ij}, ...,       lots of groups of 2
{abcde,fghij}, {abcdf, eghij}, ... ,          lots of groups of 5 
{abcdefghij}                                 1 group of 10
answer = 1073
```

I couldnt recognize which type of combinatorics this problem fits in.

Note that the order doesn't matter, {ba,dc} = {ab,cd}, so if you have counted the first, you cannot count the second.

Answer (score 1):

Given N, the number of ways is
$$\sum_{G|N} \frac{N!}{G!\cdot (P!)^G}.$$
If $G$ divides $N$ then you have $\binom{N}{P,\cdots, P}=\frac{N!}{(P!)^G}$
ways to assign to each person one of the $G$ (labeled) groups where $P=N/G$ is the size of each group. Then you divide by $G!$ so it is indifferent how the $G$ groups were labeled.

P.S. Take a look at the Sloane's sequence [A038041](https://oeis.org/A038041)

Answer (score 0):

The general answer is $$\frac{N!}{P!^GG!}$$
because you can achieve your goal by arranging all $N$ people in one of $N!$ orders, then assign the first $P$ into the first group etc.
We reach the same result in many diffrent ways because first of all we obtain an (unrequested) ordering within each group - thus we have to divide by $P!$ for each of the $G$ groups - and we obtain an (unsdesired) order among the groups themselves - thus we have to divide by $G!$.

**Edit:** Seems that you do not want $P$ (and $G$) fixed. In that case, you need to sume over the various possibilities - as *RobertZ* does in his answer.